# How can you run a command in bash over and over until success?

Tags: bash, command, while-loop

I have a script and want to ask the user for some information, but the script cannot continue until the user fills in this information. The following is my attempt at putting a command into a loop to achieve this but it doesn't work for some reason:

```sh
echo "Please change password"
while passwd
do
    echo "Try again"
done
```

I have tried many variations of the while loop:

```sh
while `passwd`
while [[ "`passwd`" -gt 0 ]]
while [ `passwd` -ne 0 ]]
# ... And much more
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 560, accepted):

```
until passwd
do
  echo "Try again"
done
```

or

```
while ! passwd
do
  echo "Try again"
done
```

Comment: oneliner: `until passwd; do echo "Try again"; done`

Comment: Difficult to Ctrl-C out of this.

Comment: If you think you're going to need to cancel this, just open up a new instance of your shell (example, type "bash") and, when you want to cancel it, go into another terminal window and kill the newly spawned bash process.

Comment: Easy to Ctr-C out of this: `until passwd; do echo "Try again"; sleep 2; done` - all you have to do is press Ctr-C right after (within the two seconds given) the `echo` did it's job.

Comment: Ctrl-Z followed by `kill %1` works here when Ctrl-C won't

Comment: What is the most simple way to keep trying only a few times ?

Comment: @azmeuk: Try something like `until passwd || (( count++ >= 5 )); do echo "foo"; done` (bash only, make sure to set count to 0 if that varaible exists) If you need this for plain sh, increment the counter in the body and use [ ]

Comment: After referring to this page many times, I decided to created a generic bash function to retry commands, here it is: https://gist.github.com/felipou/6fbec22c4e04d3adfae5

Answer (score 127):

To elaborate on @Marc B's answer,

```
$ passwd
$ while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do !!; done
```

Is a nice way of doing the same thing that's not command specific.

If you want to do this as an alias (kudos to @Cyberwiz):

```
alias rr='while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do eval $(history -p !!); done'
```

Usage:

```
$ passwd
$ rr
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately (I get '!!' command not found). How is it supposed to work?

Comment: It is a bash trick to run the previous command. For example if you forget to write `sudo` in front of a command, you can simply do `sudo !!` to run the previous command with root privileges.

Comment: How to sleep between runs?

Comment: ^^ `while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do !!; sleep 1; done`

Comment: adding `sleep 1;` won't work since it'll give out 0 as exit value and therefore end the while loop prematurely

Comment: If you want to do this as an alias, with sleep: `alias rr='while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do sleep 1; eval $(history -p !!); done'`

Answer (score 115):

You need to test `$?` instead, which is the exit status of the previous command. `passwd` exits with 0 if everything worked ok, and non-zero if the passwd change failed (wrong password, password mismatch, etc...)

```
passwd
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
    passwd
done
```

With your backtick version, you're comparing passwd's output, which would be stuff like `Enter password` and `confirm password` and the like.

Comment: I like this because it's clear how to adapt it for the opposite situation.  e.g. run a program with a non-deterministic bug until it fails

Comment: When success is indicated by a non-zero exit code, this is what you need.

Comment: I think this can be slightly improved upon by changing the first `passwd` with `/bin/false` if you have some long and complicated command that you don't want to keep two versions of.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer imho. This should work in most shells (tested in bash, mksh, and ash) and is easily adaptable to the situation.

Comment: Fails shellcheck with output: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?. [SC2181]

Comment: Precisely because of the shellcheck warning I prefer the accepted `until` answer

Answer (score 30):

If anyone looking to have retry limit:

```
max_retry=5
counter=0
until <YOUR_COMMAND>
do
   sleep 1
   [[ counter -eq $max_retry ]] && echo "Failed!" && exit 1
   echo "Trying again. Try #$counter"
   ((counter++))
done
```

Comment: `$command` isn't a great placeholder -- see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) on why using strings to store commands is innately unreliable.

Comment: I think in this example $command should just be replaced by your arbitrary command. Not necessarily used as string. I like to use <YOUR_COMMAND> to indicate user has to replace something here

Answer (score 10):

You can use an infinite loop to achieve this:

```
while true
do
  read -p "Enter password" passwd
  case "$passwd" in
    <some good condition> ) break;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: This is the only answer that didn't require putting my multi-line command in a function. I did `&& break` after my verification command though instead of the select case.

Answer (score 2):

```
while [ -n $(passwd) ]; do
        echo "Try again";
done;
```

Comment: This is not the way to do it... you're negating the stdout of psswd and then doing a unary test on it. @duckworthd is good.

Comment: Moreover, because there isn't quoting, the test is going to misbehave when there *is* output but it's more than one word, or is a glob expression that matches files in the current directory, or so forth.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes a little tricky if you want the strict mode (`set -e`) and none of above worked.

```bash
set -euo pipefail

counter=0
max_attempts=3
while ret=0; <your command> || ret=$?; [ $ret -ne 0 ]
do
  [[ $counter -eq $max_attempts ]] && echo "Command failed"; exit 1
  sleep 2
  echo "Trying again"
  counter=$((counter+1))
done
```