# How Can I Run A Command That Does Not Exit Upon Failure Until It Succeeds?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, command

I have a `Docker` container running `HBase` See [here](http://github.com/hasancansaral/hadoop-hbase-docker) for more details about it. Basically, it takes around 30s for HBase to come alive.

Obviously I have other containers depending on this one. In one of them, in `docker-entrypoint.sh` I am basically doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/command argument

while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
  sleep 2;
  /path/to/command argument
done
```

The problem here is that the `/path/to/command` is something that deploys a webserver, that would interact with `HBase` container. If it succeeds, it is blocking the current process (which is fine, since it is in a container), but in a same way, if it fails, it prints the stack trace but does not exit with some `-ne 0` code (Actually, does not exit at all). In fact, if it exits `--restart=always` would handle it.

So, my question here is that how can I keep it retrying until it succeeds, basically without exiting with some fail code? Exiting from the `Docker` container is also an option, so that it can keep restarting until success. For now, I do not have the opportunity to modify the not exiting code to exit.

### Update:

I had to do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=$(mktemp)
/path/to/command args 2> "$tmp" &

while true; do
  sleep 5;
  if [ -s "$tmp" ]; then
    exit
  fi
done
```

Basically, I had to run it in the background so that the script above would continue executing (`path/to/command` is a UI blocking command -such as `listen` of a server - that does not exit when succeeds -it listens- nor when it fails -it should have, this is why I am asking this question-).

So in order for Docker container not to exit , I had to add a `while true;` loop, in which I am checking if there is an error in`$tmp`. If there is, I simply `exit`.

### Update 2:

I changed the bash script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/command args &

while true; do
  sleep 10;
  
  response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost);

  if [ "$response" != "200" ]; then
    exit
  fi
  
done
```

since my container is deploying a web server, I am at least monitoring its status in the main thread, after starting it. Still there's room for improvement.

Comment: Side note: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274294/how-can-you-run-a-command-in-bash-over-until-success) and a few others asks the same question for an exiting process.

Comment: Might be able to redirect stderr to a file, then check if said file is not empty.

Comment: @andlrc Smart. I will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: You could also run it as a background process and join with an alarm...

Comment: @Will, I can run it as a background process, but didn't quite get/know what you meant by joining with an alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try redirecting `stderr` to a file, and then check if said file is empty:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
/path/to/command argument 2> "$tmp"

# Run code until "$tmp" is empty
until [ -s "$tmp" ]; do
  sleep 2
  /path/to/command argument 2> "$tmp"
done

rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: Should I not clear `$tmp` when I am going to run the command again?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral `2>` should do that for you. Consider `echo 1 > a;echo 2> a; od a;` will output `0000000` meaning it's empty

Comment: A quick question, will I end up with a couple of stuck processes, and one running upon success? How could I manage to exit from `Docker`container when the `$tmp` is not empty, which I believe is a better option?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Your processes will terminate when they print the stack trace, if they don't how would your code continue to execute? And the `until` loop will end when the tmp file is not empty, then remove the file. And exit.

Comment: The problem is they don't. They print the stack trace and hung, which is why I am asking this question. If they were to terminate, I would not have this issue, since Docker containers would exit then restart. I had to do it like above (see the edited post), but am not quite happy about it.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I can see it's not a pretty solution. I will inform you if I come up with something more elegant.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated!

Comment: I came up with my second update, in the original post. A little better, since I am checking the status of the web server, but there's still room for improvement, I guess.